# Android "Bad magic number" error from readBundle

Tags: android, bundle, magic-numbers, parcel

I've been using bundles to pass my information around my application and occasionally save them to a file by first passing them to a parcel.

For some reason occasionally when I try to put them back into a bundle it springs a "readBundle: bad magic number" error on me generated by the following code:

```
FileInputStream fis = myContext.openFileInput(name);

    byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
    int length = fis.read(buff,0,2048);
    fis.close();

    Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
    p.unmarshall(buff, 0, length);
    p.setDataPosition(0);
    return p.readBundle();
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://remotedroid.net/blog/2010/10/13/push-notifications-with-urban-airship-on-android/

Comment: Yah same error but I think our causes were different. Turns out that someone saved another (nonbundle) file to this area and looping over the filelist causes some issues. 

I probably should have noticed this sooner but I didnt think of it until I saw the sizes of the "parcels" I was reading in.

Comment: what is your apps JDK version?